# Repurposing Ubuntu Drive for a new PC

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I am currently dual booting Ubuntu and Win 10 on my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a 250gb SSD and Win10 on a 1TB ssd. Grub is on the Ubuntu SSD. I am building a new PC soon and haven't used ubuntu as much as I thought I would.

I would like to reformat and repurpose my 250gb Ubuntu SSD for use in my new PC as a Win10 boot drive.

Is there a procedure of doing this without any issues on my laptop or the SSD itself. My goal is to only have Win 10 on the 1TB ssd in my laptop and use the 250gb ssd for another pc basically.

Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: Migrate your Ubuntu data onto another media before placing the 250gb disk into the new machine.The Windows installer will reformat and repartition the drive. Run the Windows installer on the completed new PC with new disks in place.

Comment: New system will be UEFI. And Windows requires gpt partitioning for UEFI boot. How you boot install media is then how it installs. If old drive is gpt then that is not an  issues. If MBR(msdos) you need to convert to gpt which will normally totally erase it. Windows may just do that as it does not "see" Linux partitions.

Comment: Let me ask it this way, since grub and ubuntu are on the 250gb drive, can i simply boot into my windows os on my 1tb drive, go into disk management, completely reformat the 250gb drive, take it out of my laptop, install it on my new desktop and install windows on that?